# Composer update not working

Tags: composer-php

When I try composer update, I'm getting this:
[image]

[image]

When I try php, it's working and it's in my path. 
Any help?

Comment: Are you sure '#php' is correct?

Comment: And make the command more verbose to get more information for debugging

Comment: @Pier-LucGendreau what do you mean?

Comment: @WouterJ how can I make it verbose?

Comment: Attached one more image

Answer (score 0):

There was an error in the composer.json which belonged to the project where I was trying *composer update*[image: code snippet]

After removing *#* it started working normally.